# NotificationCenter.default.addObserver is not calling the objective C function

Tags: ios, notificationcenter

I am using swift 5 on Xcode 11.0, trying to pass a userInfo from view-controller-A to view-controller-B and I already made a notification center post in **view-controller-A** and here is the code:

```
 let uid = response["session-id"] as? String

                NotificationCenter.default.post(
                    name: NSNotification.Name("didReceiveSession"),
                    object: nil,
                    userInfo: ["uid" : uid!]
                )
```

And in **view-controller-B** I registered the notification and added an observer like so:

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(self.getSessionId),
            name: NSNotification.Name("didReceiveSession"),
            object: nil
        )
```

And here is **getSessionId**:

```
 @objc func getSessionId(_ notification: Notification)
    {
        if let data = notification.userInfo as? [String: String]
        {
            self.session_Id = data["uid"]
        }
    }
```

I tried a lot of workarounds like:

1- Change *name: NSNotification.Name("didReceiveSession")* to *name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "didReceiveSession")* in both view controllers

2- Create an instance in view-controller-A:

2.1- *share = view-controller-A()*

2.2- Change *object: nil* to *object: view-controller-A.share* in the addObserver (view-controller-B)

3- Change the selector in **view-controller-B** from *selector: #selector(self.getSessionId)* to *selector: #selector(getSessionId(_:))*

But unfortunately, all attempts did not work. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: How do you know it's not being called? Set a breakpoint on the `if let ...` in your handler function. Does that trigger? Also, set breakpoints on both the `post` and the `addObserver` call. Is `addObserver`triggered before `post`?

Comment: @Gereon I did set a breakpoint on the handler function and that's how I know it's not being called.
I also set a breakpoint on both the post and addObserver, the post is being triggered before the addObserver so nothing suspicious in that.

Comment: On the contrary. If `post` is triggered before `addObserver`, who observes the notification?

Comment: So addObserver should trigger before the post?

Comment: Absolutely. If it doesn't, there is no place for the OS to deliver the notifiaction to, and it is immediately discarded.

Comment: Oh okay, this makes sense now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very incorrect way to use Notifications.

What you want to do is pass your "sessionID" value to from `VC-A` ***to*** `VC-B` when `VC-A` is moving to / presenting `VC-B`.

Assuming you are using a **segue**...

Based on what you posted, you already have a variable / property in `VC-B`, probably:

```
var session_ID: [String] = ""
```

So, in `VC-A`, you would do something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let nextVC = segue.destination as? VCB {
        nextVC.session_ID = self.uid
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that because there is a VC in between VC-A and VC-B.
They do not come after each other, there's another VC in between. 
If I want to implement this solution it means I have to move is from VC-A to VC-Inbetween to VC-B

Comment: OK - then add the same property to `VC-Inbetween`... pass your ID string from `VC-A` to `VC-Inbetween`, and then pass it from `VC-Inbetween` to `VC-B `

Comment: Yes, it seems this is the way, after seeing the answers I realized that the notification center is not what I need because it requires VC-B to be present and active which is not logical in my case.

Comment: @S.Hasan - if this resolves your issue, you should mark it as Accepted (for the benefit of other users who come across it).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the sequence of events.

When `post` is called before `addObserver`, there is no place for the OS to deliver the notification to, and therefore the notification is discarded.

You need to make sure that you have an active observers, i.e. that `addObserver` is called before you do your `post.

Comment: Yes it seems I should pass the value using segue, not notification center because it's not logical to use in my situation.